# How can I add my field of his type of material to be used in the rule

Tags: 7, rules

I need to compare two different entities in the field after the update term.
Event: "After updating existing term"
One field is in the *drupal commerce product*, the other in a *term*. With the help of "entity has a field" do not get to add because you do not see the entitie of the product. What can be done to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is for D7
I was facing same issue some months ago, I assume that you want tocheck the Boolean value of the fields?
please confirm that is that you want to do.

To compare to different entites I did following

You might not need to add these module to achieve what you want, but they are always good to know.

[Drupal Commerce extra conditions](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_conditions)

[Drupal Commerce Extra Rules](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra)

Gives you more options when working with drupal commerce and conditions
Drupal Commerce extra rules - Well it gives you more rules to play with.

But for taxonomy term, Rules would just work out of the box.

The logic would be
a "Data comparison" condition, specify the field name, and enter "1" as the value. If the field doesn't appear in the list of fields, first add an "Entity has field" condition, and select the field there. Then add the "Data comparison" next.

1. Data Comparsion
2. Condition, give the field name you want, give the value 1.
3. If you cant find your field. You will need to add it in the above condition as "Entity has field" - or specifying "Content as type".
   Then you will choose the operator which should be == (equals)
4. Add Data comparsion. 
   (Field might have to be direct input mode)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is necessary to clarify the appropriate action.
1) I am creating a component for the rule. Opt for a plug-in "configuration actions"
2) Adding the action "Fetch entity by priorety"
3) Opt for the value of the Commerce product
4) Opt for the property - the right field to me.
5) What's in the "selector data" and "Limit result count" to specify?

Comment: To add a field from the commerce product to create "Entity has field" necessary that the selector was the Entity of the product. There is none. And for this I can not add a field from another entity for processing in the rule. If I add "Entity as type" there also can not choose the selector entity product. Field of the term is added and I can work with him in the rule.

Comment: I added Condition "Entity exists by Property." Chose the type of entity commerce product, in the property set name of field. In the value set 1. In list of selektor i can't find the entity of commerce product for chose his field.